# git rebase after pull

Tags: git, rebase, pull

I typically use `git pull --rebase` if I'm working directly on master (which I try not to do anyway). In the event that I forgot to do a rebase and just did `git pull`, is there a way to undo that and make it linear, rather than having a merge? Would doing a rebase at this point be a bad idea (if that would even accomplish anything)?

I know I can put enable rebasing on pulls by default so I don't forget, but this is more of an issue of understanding what to do in this case.

Comment: i guess `git reset --hard` back to before the pull and redo the pull is the way.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please post that as an answer rather than a comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i guess `git reset --hard` back to before the pull and redo the pull is the way

Answer (score 16):

Short answer (already given by @Alex in comments): `git reset --hard HEAD^`, but *only if there's a merge commit* (otherwise you're just backing up one commit from your fast-forward).

Long version with explanation:

`git pull` is really just `git fetch` followed by `git merge` (unless you override with `--rebase`, as you note).  So you just need to see if you got an actual merge commit or not:

```
$ git pull
Updating 171ce6f..523bacb
Fast-forward
 mp.py |   24 ++++++++++++++++++++++++
 1 files changed, 24 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 mp.py
```

In this case there was no merge commit, just a fast-forward, so, no problem—there are no changes to rebase!  If you do a `git log` you'll see the lack-of-merge-commit, especially if you do the graph-y ones below.

Let's force a merge.

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
HEAD is now at 171ce6f ignore *.log files
```

[now I'm one behind `remotes/origin/master`]

```
$ echo '# pointless comment' >> selfref.py
$ git add selfref.py 
$ git commit -m 'added to force merge'
[master 260e129] added to force merge
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
$ git pull
Merge made by recursive.
 mp.py |   24 ++++++++++++++++++++++++
 1 files changed, 24 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 mp.py
```

We can see that this happened, even if the above text is missing, with:

```
$ git log --graph --decorate --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline
*   c261bad (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'master' of [ssh url]
|\  
| * 523bacb (origin/master, origin/HEAD) add multiprocessing example
* | 260e129 added to force merge
|/  
* 171ce6f ignore *.log files
```

We want to get the local branch name `master` to point to (in this case) 260e129 again.  Fortunately that's really easy to name:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD^
260e1297900b903404c32f3706b0e3139c043ce0
```

(The other parent of the current, two-parent, merge commit is `HEAD^2`.)  So:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
HEAD is now at 260e129 added to force merge
```

and now we can rebase onto `remotes/origin/master` (I'll use the really short name, `origin`, to name that):

```
$ git rebase origin
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: added to force merge
```

Now the graph-y one-line log shows:

```
$ git log --graph --decorate --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline
* 4a0b2e2 (HEAD, master) added to force merge
* 523bacb (origin/master, origin/HEAD) add multiprocessing example
* 171ce6f ignore *.log files
```

From all of this, you should be able to figure out what to do if you run `git pull` and it complains that the merge fails. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I want to give you some advice which helps to keep history linear. Set the following git configuration for rebasing the branch automatically when you make pull.

```
$ git config branch.autosetuprebase always
```

After applying this setting you do not need to type full pull command with `--rebase` parameter, just `git pull`.

More information you can get in this article 
http://stevenharman.net/git-pull-with-automatic-rebase

Comment: As stated in my question, I know I can do this. I'm just trying to learn what to do in this case.

Comment: In git versions >= 1.7.9 this is 

`git config --global pull.rebase true`